# Spring multiaction controller validation is not working

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Hi I am using spring 2.5 in my project. I have used validation. I am able to call the validation but the problem is validation error message is not displaying in jsp page. Can u please show me any example on Multiaction

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to perform Spring validation in MultiActionController?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2744587/how-to-perform-spring-validation-in-multiactioncontroller)

Answer (score 0):

When you have validation errors you have to add then to an attribute on HttpServletRequest as per the tag you have used on your JSP page. If you used spring form tag then add those errors to "errors" attribute. Otherwise set errors to name you have used for rendering on JSP page.