# Spring Validation on MultiActionController, BindException : how to use custom object name instead of command

Tags: java, spring-mvc, validation

Sorry for my dumb question and bad English. 
i trying to make some validation on user change password menu in my new Developed Web using Spring MVC.

i follow instruction from [How to perform Spring validation in MultiActionController?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2744587/how-to-perform-spring-validation-in-multiactioncontroller)

i write this code :

```
public ModelAndView hanldeBindException(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, ServletRequestBindingException bindingException) {
    BindException bindException = (BindException) bindingException.getRootCause();
    ModelMap modelmap = new ModelMap();
    ChangePasswordForm cpForm = new ChangePasswordForm();
    cpForm.setUsername(SessionHelper.getUsername());
    modelmap.addAttribute("ChangePasswordForm", cpForm);
    return new ModelAndView("changepassword").addAllObjects(bindException.getModel()).addObject("ChangePasswordForm", cpForm);
}
```

and in my jsp :

```
<form:form action="update.htm" commandName="ChangePasswordForm" >
    <form:errors path="*" cssClass="errorblock" element="div" />
    <table  class="form">
        <tr>
            <td class="col1"><label>User Name :</label></td>
            <td class="col2"><form:label path="username" >${ChangePasswordForm.username}</form:label></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label>Old Password :</label></td>
            <td><form:password path="oldPassword" id="oldPassword"></form:password>
                <form:errors path="oldPassword" cssClass="error" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label>New Password :</label></td>
            <td><form:password path="newPassword"></form:password>
            <form:errors path="newPassword" cssClass="error" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label>Confirm New Password :</label></td>
            <td><form:password path="confirmNewPassword"></form:password>
            <form:errors path="confirmNewPassword" cssClass="error" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="submit" ></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form:form>
```

but it does not appear any error on my screen when i try negative test like empty field. 
when i try to print out

```
System.out.println("UserController::hanldeBindException::1" + bindException.getObjectName());
```

it show the object name is "command" instead of my command name in jsp which is "ChangePasswordForm". When i try to change that commandName to "command" it works. But i just curious is there some way to setObjectName in BindException Class or you have another way to use custom name instead of default "command" Object Name??

**UPDATE**

My Validation works since i change commandName to "command"  to like this :

```
<form:form action="update.htm" commandName="command">
   <!-- Form Field and Error define here -->
</form:form>
```

and of course do some adjustment in my controller also. if i change it to another name it wont work anymore.

I use Spring Framework 3.0.2 RELEASE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simple answer would be that most likely you're extending BaseCommandController in some form (AbstractCommandController or otherwise), in which case you should probably override the "getCommandName()" and "getCommand()" methods.  But i can't tell from the code you've supplied.

what version of spring are you using?  The idea of a "command" is relatively antiquated now as of 3.0+ as are the base classes.  Instead use annotation based controllers and model attributes:

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes({"changePasswordForm"})
public class MyController {
    @InitBinder
    public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
       binder.setValidator(new ChangePasswordFormValidator());
    }

    @ModelAttribute("changePasswordForm")
    public ChangePasswordForm createChangePasswordForm() {
      ...
    }


    @RequestMapping(...)
    public ModelAndView controllerMethod(
          @Valid @ModelAttribute changePasswordForm ChangePasswordForm) {
      ...
    }
}
```

This should automatically validate your form before calling the controller method, and bounce back to the calling page.

In your validator, you'll supply error message code in the validate method:

```
public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
    ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "username", "username.required");
}
```

You would then make sure "username.required" is a key in whatever MessageSource you've supplied to spring.

The form tags should work exactly as you have them.

Here's the spring reference manual for controllers:

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-controller